# My [javascript] tag wiki excerpt edit got denied

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

[Link to the denied edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27584733)

Recently when I've seen the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag's excerpt, I see 2 errors. One of them is a forgotten space in a list:

> ... associated with the tags [node.js], [jquery],[json], and [html]
>                                         `^`

and another is improper grammar:

> This tag is rarely used alone but is most often associated with the tags
>                           `^`

For the latter, the `but` should be changed to an `and`.

> This tag is rarely used alone and is most often associated with the tags

`but` is the wrong word here, because by saying `but` you're saying that everything after the `but` means the opposite of everything before the `but`, but here it's being used like an `and`, which says that the phrases on both sides of the `and` mean the same thing.

An example of a proper use of `but`:

> This tag is rarely used alone but it sometimes is. (there's an implied " used alone" after the "is")

Currently my suggested edit has 1 supported and 2 rejectors. I would like to know why people would   be against this edit asit seems clear that this should be accepted.

Comment: That look like minor edits to me and some reviewers in that queue expect edits that substantially improve a post. I doubt this edit would be in that category.

Comment: @rene Edits 54, 56, 58, and 61 are all "minor edits" like this one. This fixes errors from 60 & 62.

Comment: Changing the conjunction from "but" to "and" is not just "Fixed grammar"; you're changing the meaning of the sentence. I would think that deserves a bit more explanation in the edit summary.

Comment: The point is, even thought it might be a grammar mistake, it's still the _smalllest thing ever_. Who cares whether or not there is a space after a comma? It's not really a big deal imo. If grammar mistakes are affecting the readability of the post, then you can fix it. And plus, for fixing grammar, you are changing the meaning of the sentence as well.

Comment: but fixing mistakes is the *entire point* of editing.....

Comment: @Samathingamajig Fixing a posts readibility or improving a posts readability is the entire point of editing.

Comment: The remedy for this is the same as it ever was: earn enough rep to gain editing privileges and you can make the edits unilaterally, without getting anyone's approval.  I went ahead and made your comma fix, but elected to leave the `but`.

Comment: Can *anyone* explain why the `but` is determined to be correct here, except for people not wanting things to change

Comment: That might be a good question for https://english.stackexchange.com/ Personally, it *feels* better to me with "but," but I couldn't explain why that is.

Comment: @Sam Frankly, I think people are being a bit silly here. I think your "and" edit is appropriate, "but" feels weirdly disjointed to me in that sentence. My thought is that people are just stingier about tag excerpt edits than about Q/A ones, which is why an edit like this might get rejected on a tag but accepted for a post.

Comment: @Zcoop98 I disagree, because switching and to but can change the meaning of the sentence entirely.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a nice suggestion but it would take a lot of extra rep! (20k for unilateral edits to tag wikis and excerpts.)

Comment: @10Rep Except, in the given case, there is no can- it *doesn't* change the meaning. And to Sam's credit, the "but" is being used semantically as an "and" anyway. In the excerpt, both "this tag is rarely used alone" *and* "this tag is often used with tags A, B, & C" are true. That sounds like it should be an "and" to me.

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't know...it seems more correct using but. And even that doesn't decrease readability, does it? One can make a case to accept it, and decline it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is worth mentioning in this case it was a tag excerpt which needs serious rep to edit without review ....

Comment: Come now, @rene, there's nothing serious about rep.

Answer (score 11):

As one of the reviewers who rejected your suggested edit, I can only say that I was *thinking* about accepting it, for a while ... because of the argument you made above concerning the use of "and" *versus* "but" as the contested conjunction.

However, I felt that, of itself, that really wasn't a significant improvement (even with the comma-space thing).

Perhaps, on another day, with better coffee, I would have *indirectly* approved your suggestion by improving it to:

> This tag is rarely used alone; rather, it is most often associated with
> the tags...

But that would have meant me making *considerably* more changes (in character terms) than you had - which is generally a criterion I use for "Reject and Edit."